# Brining salt concentration

Tags: brining

I have seen a lot of different advice about how saturated to make a brining solution.

In my case I would be more likely to brine either meat or vegetables prior to pickling.

A quart of water can dissolve up to about 350 grams of salt, but most of the brine suggestions I have seen have only about 35-40 grams of salt which is only about 10% of saturation. Is this correct?

Comment: It really depends on what you're making. I'm not sure what you mean by brining "prior to pickling" -- ordinarily the brine itself would be used during pickling.

Comment: @Sneftel Ok, so you are saying that brining is basically part of the recipe and that it is dish dependent? The problem I have with that is that many recipes I have seen just say "brine the onions for one day" or whatever and do not indicate the salt concentration to be used.

Comment: For that sort of thing it doesn't much matter. 10% w/w (i.e. ~100g/liter) would be pretty normal, but 5% or 20% w/w would likely produce equally acceptable results.